# ServiceStack service unable to return dynamic response object, both as Json and XML

Tags: xml, dynamic, servicestack

I've built a service, that combines and returns a set of dynamic json data from an external service. Returning the data as json is fine - but XML...

I've tried returning it as raw XML in a string-property of the DTO (using JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode), but then the xml-characters in the string gets escaped, in the final ServiceStack response.

I've tried returning the data as a dynamic/object, and again json is fine, but XML throws a lot of DataContractSerializer runtime-errors.

This, supposedly simple thing, is driving me up the wall. Can anyone please post an example where dynamic data is returnable both as json and xml, by the same service/operation (depending on the Accept-header)?

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack uses [.NET's XML DataContractSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/serialization-and-deserialization) to serialize your DTOs by default. If that's unsuitable you can [register your own XML Content Type Serializer](https://docs.servicestack.net/serialization-deserialization#custom-media-types) to take over XML Serialization which includes an example to [replace ServiceStack's default DataContractSerializer to use .NET's XmlSerializer](https://docs.servicestack.net/serialization-deserialization#encapsulate-inside-a-plugin).

> I've tried returning it as raw XML in a string-property of the DTO (using JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode), but then the xml-characters in the string gets escaped, in the final ServiceStack response.

This is incorrect, ServiceStack lets you [return a number of raw data types](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-return-types) like a raw XML `string` which it writes directly to the response `OutputStream`, there might be something else escaping it after it writes it to the Response (e.g. Web Server or Client), but it's not ServiceStack.

An alternative strategy to control XML Serialization is to copy them into DTOs annotated with `DataContract` or `XmlSerializer` attributes which will allow you to control how the XML is serialized however that would be tedious for dynamic data, of which XML is generally a poor choice as serializing .NET's generic data collections produces ugly XML.

#### Content-Type Specific Implementations

If you only need to handle the XML for this one Service, instead of overriding the default XML Serializer implementation you can use ServiceStack's [Content-Type Specific Implementations](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#content-type-specific-service-implementations) to handle XML Requests differently, e.g:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    // Handles all other unspecified Verbs/Formats
    public object Any(MyRequest request) => ...;

    // Handles any XML Requests
    public object AnyXml(MyRequest request)
    {
        var dto = Any(request);
        string xml = CustomXmlSerializer(dto);
        return xml;
    }
}
```